# How to show one instance of data from API at the time in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an API where data is structured like this:

```
{
 "questions"
  |
  |
   "question": "What is 2+2?"
   "options"
     |
     |
      "Option 1": 2
      "Option 2": 6
      "Option 3": 1
   "question": "What is the capitol of Sweden?"
      "Option 1": "Stockholm"
      "Option 2": "South America"
      "Option 3": "Oceania"
}
```

I want to display one question and it's alternatives at a time, then on click of a "Next"-button display the next question. The amount of questions and whatnot changes, so it has to be dynamically rendered.

I figured I can't do it with *ngFor as I only want to render the next one upon clicking the button so I'm a bit unsure how to do it.

Might be possible to figure out the length of the "questions"-array and render the next one by saving which question-index you're currently at and change to the next one by doing something like

```
<h2>${questions[i].question}</h2>
<p *ngFor="option of questions[i].options">${questions[i].options}</p>
```

But I'm unsure exactly how that would be implemented.

Comment: Try this: <p *ngFor="option of questions[i].options; let i = index">${questions[i].options}</p> And then use the i variable to access the index

Comment: What you are looking for is a **carousel**. The most common usecase for carousel are image slideshows, but your questions can use it too.nThere are ready to use components on the web. Or implement a custom structure directive, like this one. https://netbasal.com/building-a-simple-carousel-component-with-angular-3a94092b7080

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, i'd do something like this:

```html
<h2>${currentQuestion.question}</h2>
<div *ngFor="option of currentQuestion.options">${option}
<button (click)="getNextQuestion()">Next</button>
</div>
```

In the typescript file:

```js
interface Question = ... // define data structure


ngOnInit(): void {
   this.questions = ... // get questions from API
}

private _questionIndex: number = 0;
currentQuestion: Question = this.questions[this._questionIndex];
getNextQuestion(): void {
    // handle case where the index is bigger than the array
    ...
    // else
    this.currentQuestion = this.questions[++this._questionIndex];
}
```

It's also possible to use an Observable and Async Pipe for this:

```js
$question: BehaviorSubject<Question> = new BehaviorSubject<Question>();
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.questions = ... // fetch from api
  
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.$question.next(this.questions[this._questionIndex]);
}

getNextQuestion(): void {
    this.$question.next(this.questions[++this._questionIndex]);
}
```

```html
<h2>${($question | async).question}</h2>
<div *ngFor="option of ($question | async).options">${option}
<button (click)="getNextQuestion()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Also, i might add the the way your data is structured won't be feasible in javascript, because in an object, every key must be unique. you would have to map the data from the api into a valid JS object.

Also, I am unsure if you want to render one question at a time, or only render the next question if the last one has been answered. I assumed the former.

If the case is the latter, you can apply the Observable-style pattern in another `ngFor`-directive, which iterates another array which holds all the questions already answerered + the question currently being answered.

Comment: Thanks for the great input. I solved it using the index method. When the index === options.length the "Next"-button is swapped for a "Submit"-button. I think the async/pipe method would be better, but I'm a bit green with Angular so I'm sticking to my less elegant, working method for now :)

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you should try to identify the component that can be reused.

If you create a single component that is responsible for showing a question and re-use it when clicking on next or previous to show the next/previous question.

Eg:
Create a component: `<Question [input]="currentQuestion" (output)="doSomethingOnSelction(currentQuestion, $event)">`

Now you have a component that can show different questions based on input and give you a selection you can store somewhere.

You can update the current question based on the next and previous button events.
On next you can assign currentQuestion the next question in iteration.